# Bootstrap image grid alignment

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, image, gridview

I am working on an image gallery with filters. I have used a Bootstrap grid with 3 columns. My image width remains the same for all but height differs.

I am attaching the pic of how it shows currently.
[image]

But how I need it to be:
[image]

Note: I haven't written any CSS for the image grid.

Comment: Could you please include any steps you've taken to solve the issue? More than likely, very few people here are going to want to redesign the entire layout and share their full code.

Comment: It is not possible with bootstrap as all columns are floated -> https://www.bootply.com/dtwYRfKehe; take a look at https://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: Place all the images in 1 row of 3 cols, images will stack.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest **Freewall**. It is a cross-browser and responsive jQuery plugin to help you create many types of grid layouts: flexible layouts, images layouts, nested grid layouts, metro style layouts, pinterest like layouts ... with nice CSS3 animation effects and call back events. Freewall is all-in-one solution for creating dynamic grid layouts for desktop, mobile, and tablet.

Home page and document: also found [here.](http://kombai.github.io/freewall/)